# How to Validate a RSA256 signed JWT token in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have JWT token which is RSA256 signed. I need to validate this token in my my microservice.

Can anyone give a example of how to implement this using Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a springboot resource server to handle the JWT token and security. Check spring document for [resource server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server.html)

Comment: Url return 404.